# I am trying to make an application that will make phone calls one after another from the list of number

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, node.js, excel

I am developing an application for my friend who is in sales, this application will make phone calls one after another, as soon as one phone call gets disconnected, it will automatically make call to another number from the list. This list can be read from and xml data source or json or mongodb or even from excel sheet.

This could be an ios app that reads data from an end point and stores them and can initiate the call at any point and it wont stop until all the calls are made.

Next call will be made only after the first call has been finished.

I am thinking about using node based web app using google voice to trigger the chain.

I've no experience with ios / android apis but Im willing to work on that if it's a viable thing on that platform.

Note: what we're trying to avoid is whole process of

1. looking up the phone number.
2. touch hangup and then click for another phone number.
3. It should self trigger the next call as soon as current call gets disconnected.
4. Also we're trying to avoid any paid services like twillo.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

for IOS, you could use [CTCallCenter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/ctcallcenter)

```
self.callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call){

        if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
        {
            //NSLog(@"call stopped");
        }
        else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
        {
        }
        else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
        {
            //NSLog(@"call played");
        }
        else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
        {

        }
    };
```

Download phone list, loop inside phone list, make a call, listening for CTCallCenter and appdelegate's Event, detect user have finish last call, our app active again, then make the next call.

Or you can try in [Demo here](https://github.com/lantranduc/demoCall.git) !

Comment: Will the new call dialing will happen by itself ?  I mean i wont have to touch any button on the phone ?

Comment: It could be. I will create a Demo for you. Maybe to night, JAPAN time.

Comment: https://github.com/lantranduc/demoCall.git send you demo. Main function is working, just custom it.